# VBA assigning cell value from array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an excel report that relies on 3 source documents for data.
The report pulls and compiles the 3 sources into 1 array. It then loops through the array and assigns the values to the columns of the appropriate row in the appropriate spreadsheet.

I am currently getting a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" at a specific point.

The report loops through the array and assigns the cell values successfully until the 6th column which represents "Shift Worked". the value in the array is "Variant/Date" type and = #3:53:54 AM#

Please help, I have scanned the archives for this specific problem and cannot find anything that seems to pertain to this instance.

Code:

```
Sub Write_Data(v() As Variant)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim d As Date, d2 As Date
    Dim s() As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    d = CDate(frmMain.txtDate)

    For i = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
        sName = v(3, i)
        s = Split(sName)
        sName = Left(Trim(s(LBound(s))), 1) & Trim(s(UBound(s)))
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            If UCase(Trim(sName)) = UCase(Trim(ws.Name)) Then Exit For
        Next
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            r = 5
            Do
                r = r + 1
                If InStr(ws.Cells(r, 1), "-") Then
                    s = Split(ws.Cells(r, 1), "-")
                    d2 = CDate(s(LBound(s)))
                    If d2 = d Then
                        For j = LBound(v, 1) + 3 To UBound(v, 1)
                            c = j - 2
                            ws.Cells(r, c) = v(j, i) ' <- This is where the error
                        Next j
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    d2 = 0
                End If
            Loop Until r > 35
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

===============

## UPDATED:

I figured this out.

Previously, I was doing this:
During the compilation of the array, in order to get the correct value for the 6th field, I  used a function to compile 8 Different possible timeclock punches into a total "Shift Worked" Value.

The error was occuring because if there was a missing punch then I was using "Now()" to get the current timestamp. Conceptually this was sound because this report would be run at the end of every hour and if the agent wouldn't have punched out yet it would add their time up until the current hour by using the "Now()" function.

The problem is this...
When running the report for a previous date, the calculation would somehow result in a correct looking "Variant/Date" type but cause a '1004' runtime error when trying to assign it to a cell.

I fixed this by adding 2 parameters for user input before running the procedure.
1. "Date" & 2. "Hour". When encountering a missing punch, instead of using "Now()" I replace that with my own variable "dNow" which simple takes the date parameter and adds the hour to it to get the latest possible time.

Here is the corrected procedure that is used to create the value that was causing an error when trying to place it. Notice the variable "dNow" and the way it is assigned.

```
Function Calc_Time(t1 As Date, t2 As Date) As Date
    Dim dNow As Date
    dNow = DateAdd("h", frmMain.cmbHour, DateValue(frmMain.txtDate))
    Dim t As Date
    If t1 <> 0 And t2 <> 0 Then
        t = (TimeValue(t2) - TimeValue(t1))
    ElseIf t1 <> 0 And t2 = 0 Then
        t = (TimeValue(dNow) - TimeValue(t1))
    ElseIf t1 = 0 And t2 <> 0 Then
        t = t2
    ElseIf t1 = 0 And t2 = 0 Then
        t = 0
    End If
    Calc_Time = t
End Function
```

Comment: do a debug.print on all r,c,j,i before the line of error, see if each of them gives you a valid value.  If that passed, debug.print on v(j,i).  Also try use v(j,i).value

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too narrow and it only applies to one specific case.